# Nodejs Twit and Twitter API, how to change users?

Tags: node.js, twitter-oauth

I have this code using [Twit](https://github.com/ttezel/twit)

```
var Twit = require('twit')

var T = new Twit({
  consumer_key:         'my creds'
, consumer_secret:      'my creds'
, access_token:         'my creds'
, access_token_secret:  'my creds'
});

T.get('statuses/home_timeline', { count: 200 },  function (err1, data1, response1) {
    console.log( JSON.stringify(data1) );
});
```

This works perfectly well, however, only for my **own** tweets, how can I authenticate another user?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use 3-legged authentication outlined here: [3-legged](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/3-legged).

It is a bit involved to do it yourself, but here is one implementation: [twitter 3-legged](http://webapplog.com/node-js-oauth1-0-and-oauth2-0-twitter-api-v1-1-examples/).

Comment: The article you linked mentions 3 legged OAuth, but does it actually implement it?

Comment: It has a code example, but it does rely on the [oauth package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth) to implement the OAuth API.